# How can I convert a JSON file to a html page in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, json, ruby

I am writing a website which takes as a URL get parameter a link to a JSON file and converts it to a good looking html page (i.e. not a table). Part of this requires a recursive function to parse the JSON file. What I would like is the keys to look like html headers. Each value in an Array to be on a separate line and strings to have a bold key with the value being on the same line. Most importantly I would like the page to indent the content of the JSON file as you would expect a JSON file to be indented.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi everyone, firstly I am sorry this question is not right for stack overflow. What I intended to do was answer my own question (see my answer below) so that other people with the same question as me could have a good example of how to solve this. Please could you advice me on how to rewrite my question keeping in mind the answer I posted? Also @AndreyDeineko I understand that JSON and HTML are 2 completely different things but there are cases (such as my own) where it would be necessary to convert 1 file format to another. I don't believe your comment was very productive.

Comment: @AndreyDeineko comments should ask for clarification or criticize in a constructive manner. If you find the question not good you can downvote it. Making comments like yours does not in any way help or contribute to the quality or user experience of the Stack Overflow community. It is just unnecessary.

Comment: @Brad I have read this before and after reading it again I still do not see why my post is not a good question. (I am not disagreeing with you just trying to learn). I understand that in just a few minutes at least 7 people down voted it so there must be something wrong with it but I don't see what could you please help explain what is wrong?

Comment: @KNejad There is another site as part of the stackoverflow mansion called http://codereview.stackexchange.com/. I think your question would fit well in there

Comment: @KNejad The reason it is downvoted and will eventually be closed it that it's just too broad as it is, and also doesn't show any effort on your part. If you had included some part of your answer you would have gotten much better response, since the answer shows that you definitely know what you're doing

Comment: @Iceman Thanks for your reply. Firstly does the updated question work any better? Also I had 9 reputation before (which I know is very little) And now after this question I am back down to 1. Is there any way for me to regain this lost reputation? As I feel like it is unfair for me to lose all my reputation when I was just trying to help others who might have the same problem as I did.

Comment: @KNejad If you're worried about your reputation points, which you really shouldn't everybody makes mistakes on this site when starting out, you can try deleting the question.

Comment: thanks mods, you've done it again, i found the exact question i wanted but you closed it. why do you do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this recursive function does a good job at converting the JSON file to a pretty html page.

```
def parse(hash, iteration=0 )
    iteration += 1
    output = ""
    hash.each do |key, value|

        if value.is_a?(Hash)
            output += "<div class='entry' style='margin-left:#{iteration}em'> <span style='font-size:#{250 - iteration*20}%'>#{key}: </span><br>"
            output += parse(value,iteration)
            output += "</div>"
        elsif value.is_a?(Array)
            output += "<div class='entry' style='margin-left:#{iteration}em'> <span style='font-size:#{250 - iteration*20}%'>#{key}: </span><br>"
            value.each do |value|
                if value.is_a?(String) then
                    output += "<div style='margin-left:#{iteration}em'>#{value} </div>"
                else
                    output += parse(value,iteration-1)
                end
            end
            output += "</div>"

        else
            output += "<div class='entry' style='margin-left:#{iteration}em'> <span style='font-weight: bold'>#{key}: </span>#{value}</div>"
        end
    end
    return output
end
```

Here is how it works. You pass it a hash Which you get by converting the JSON file to a hash:

```
    jsonFile = JSON.load(open(params["url"] ))
    @output = parse(jsonFile)
```

And the function checks each value in the hash and does 1 of 3 things:

1. If it is an array outputs each array element on a new line
2. If it is a string outputs the key and the value on the same line
3. If it is another Hash calls the same function

After this all you have to do it output the @output variable to the screen on the view file:

```
<%= @output.html_safe %>
```

What the iteration does is keep track of how many times the function has been called so that the output can be indented correctly

I hope this helps anybody else who is trying to do the same thing.